# Left nav menu using BS3 overlapping footer

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Essentially, my side menu is overlapping the footer and I can't seem to clear the footer to fix it.

Here is my test file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Bootstrap Side Menu Tests
        </title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->


        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->
        <style>
        #footer_container{
            width: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #footer_container ul
        {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        }

        #footer_container ul li { display: inline; }

        #footer_container ul li a
        {
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: .2em 1em;
        }

        </style>            
    </head>
    <body>

        <a href="#content" class="sr-only">Skip to main content</a>

        <div class="page-header">
          <h1>My Site</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-2" id="menu">

                <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <h2>Sidebar</h2>
                        <ul class="nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Menu A 
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Menu A 
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Menu A 
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Menu A 
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Menu A 
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Menu A 
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Menu A 
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Menu A 
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Menu A 
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Menu A 
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Menu A 
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </nav>

            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-10" id="content">          
                <h1>Stats Home</h1>
            </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
    <hr/>
         <footer>
            <div id="footer_container">
                <ul class="inline">  
                <li><a href="/default.cfm">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about.cfm">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact.cfm">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>          
      </footer>
    </div>


    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/B2c54/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.navbar-collapse {max-height: 999em;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/B2c54/3

Alternatvely, set a max-height on your `ul`:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/B2c54/4

```
ul.nav {
    max-height: 250px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

You'd want to apply media query specification for this approach so it doesn't affect mobile.

Comment: applying it to the .navbar-collapse also expands the entire menu when in mobile (resizing browser) which I like (as opposed to seeing scroll bars).

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the  **.navbar-collapse** class. The max-height is defined in the css. Try changing the value.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be declaring the 'sidebar' as part of your navbar. While I can sort of see your rationale behind doing this (I'm guessing it's to have the sidebar collapse into the navbar on smaller screens) I would personally not recommend this. Bootstrap defines clear components and doesn't seem to play well with attempts to modify their layouts with CSS. I would recommend looking to the examples page (it sounds like you've already read through the main documentation) for inspiration on responsive sidebars rather than trying to repurpose the navbar component as a sidebar.

Hope that helps, sorry it's not a more direct answer